# Accents not shown on j2me

Tags: java, java-me, character-encoding

I'm building a j2me app in french, but it doesn't show certain strings not right. For instance: "Cette page donne un aperçu des dernières nouvelles" becomes "Cette page donne un eperÃϨ"res nouvelles".

Does anyone know why this is?

Comment: does your phone support french ?

Comment: yes it does. I'm using the kuix framework though. Maybe this has something to do with it?

Comment: how do you display string on screen ? are u storing somewhere and then reading or reading over the air or something ?

Answer (score 0):

That funny `ÃϨ` string is what UTF-8 looks like when displayed in a program that's expecting ASCII or Windows-1252.  Are you sure the software on the phone is set to UTF-8, and/or the encoding header on the data stream matches the actual encoding?

For example, if this is XML and the header said Windows-1252 but the actual encoding was UTF-8, and the phone software respected the header, this would be the result.